# How do I get telegram to display an info card of my site

Tags: telegram

I use telegram quite a bit. I have a site but telegram never displays it little info card, it works for sites like stackoverflow.com, google.com etc. Doesn't work for mine or minecraft.net and some other sites. My site uses: `<meta property="og:title" content="Amazing Title">` which I think is what Telegram is supposed to get this info from right? What am I doing wrong here? Is Telegram just picky when it's going to show the card or does it use something else to load the contents of it's info card?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Telegram get previews using two protocols:

1. [Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/overview)
2. [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/)

In order to get your page previewed you need to add necessary metatags for, at least, one of them.